# How can I overload a built-in module in python?

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to bind hosts to specified ips in my python program. Just make it affect in the python program, so I am not going to modify the `/etc/hosts` file.

I tried to add a bit code to the `create_connection` function in `socket.py` for host-ip translation, like this:

```
host, port = address  # the original code in socket.py
# My change here:
if host == "www.google.com":
    host = target_ip  
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM): # the original code in socket.py
```

I found it works fine.

And now I want the host-ip translation only works in this python program.

**So my question is:** how can I make my python program import this socket.py not the build-in one when using `import socket`?

To make it clear, here is an example. Suppose 'test' is my work directory:

```
test
|--- main.py
|--- socket.py
```

In this case:

1. How can I make main.py use test/socket.py by `import socket`?
2. How can I make another modules use test/socket.py when they are
       using `import socket`?

I think changing the module find path order may help. But I found that even if the current path(`''`) is in the first place of `sys.path` already and `import socket` still imports the built-in scoket module.

Comment: A good practice is to get the standard `socket` when you `import socket`, and explictly import the alternative when you want the alternative, e.g. `from test import socket` or `from . import socket`. Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: @shx2 In this way, when work together with a third party module, such as `requests`, I need to change every import statement using the third party module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can monkey-patch `sys.modules`, placing your own module instead of the standard `socket`, before importing any other module which might be using it.

```
# myscript.py

from myproject import mysocket
import sys
sys.modules['socket'] = mysocket

# ... the rest of your code
import requests
...
```

For that, `mysocket` should expose everything which the standard `socket` does.

```
# mysocket.py

import socket as _std_socket
from socket import *  # expose everything

def create_connection(address, *args, **kwargs):
    if address == ...:
       address = ...
    return _std_socket.create_connection(address, *args, **kwargs)
```

This might be an over-simplification of what `mysocket.py` should look like. Youd' likely need to add some definitions before this can be used in production, but you get the idea.

---

Another approach would be to monkey-patch the `socket` module itself, i.e. overwrite names inside the original module.

```
# myscript.py
import socket

def create_connection2(...):
    ...

socket.create_connection = create_connection2

# ... the rest of your code
import requests
...
```

I prefer the former approach, becuase it is cleaner in the sense you don't need to go *inside* the module, only to hide it and override some things in it from the outside.

Comment: Thanks, `sys.modules['socket'] = mysocket` is what I want!

Answer (score 1):

You can use relative imports to locally use a socket.py module. However, to do this your project must be [structured as a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py).

```
from . import socket
```